# EEVEE Volumetric Light exlusion

Tags: light, volumetrics, eevee-render-engine

I need to exclude a point light from volumetrics lights.

I tried placing a cube that surround only the spot light with a "Volume Scatter" node but it catch also volumetrics from the point light.

[image]

It will be great to have a "no volumetrics" checkbox like "shadows" checkbox.

[image]

Hope someone can help. Thank you!

Comment: Blender 2.93 has this feature!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to go to the World node editor, then add a *Volume Scatter* node and plug it into the *Volume parameter* in the *World Output* node.

[image: screenshot of the node setup]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I’m not sure you answered to my question... I need a way to EXCLUDE some lights!